# How come the firestore document data being called is not populating the my collection view when running the app?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

Here is the code for this section:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuthCombineSwift
import Foundation

struct Booking {
    let customerName: String
    let customerAddress: String
    let dateTime: Timestamp
    let description: String
    let bookingID: String
    
    var formattedDateTime: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: dateTime.dateValue())
    }


        init(customerName: String, customerAddress: String, dateTime: Timestamp, description: String, bookingID: String) {
            self.customerName = customerName
            self.customerAddress = customerAddress
            self.dateTime = dateTime
            self.description = description
            self.bookingID = bookingID
        }
    }
    class BookingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customerNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customerAddressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    }
        class WorkersViewController: UICollectionViewController{
            

        @IBOutlet var bookingsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
          
        var bookings: [Booking] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("In viewDidLoad")
            bookingsCollectionView.delegate = self
               bookingsCollectionView.dataSource = self
               bookingsCollectionView.register(BookingCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "bookingCell")
               fetchBookings()
           }

            func fetchBookings() {
                Firestore.firestore().collection("customers").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching bookings: \(error)")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                                  print("Error: documents are nil")
                                  return
                              }
                              self.bookings = documents.compactMap { document in
                                  guard let customerName = document.data()["name"] as? String,
                                      let customerAddress = document.data()["address"] as? String,
                                      let timestamp = document.data()["dateTime"] as? Timestamp,
                                      let description = document.data()["description"] as? String else {
                                          print("Error: document data could not be converted to the required types")
                                          return nil
                                  }
                        return Booking(customerName: customerName, customerAddress: customerAddress, dateTime: timestamp, description: description, bookingID: document.documentID)
                    }
                    print("Reloading collection view data")
                    self.bookingsCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }
            extension WorkersViewController {
              override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return bookings.count
              }

              override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "bookingCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingCollectionViewCell
                  print("Configuring cell for indexPath \(indexPath)")
                let booking = bookings[indexPath.item]
                  if let customerNameLabel = cell.customerNameLabel, let customerAddressLabel = cell.customerAddressLabel, let dateTimeLabel = cell.dateTimeLabel, let descriptionLabel = cell.descriptionLabel {
                      customerNameLabel.text = booking.customerName
                      customerAddressLabel.text = booking.customerAddress
                      dateTimeLabel.text = booking.formattedDateTime
                      descriptionLabel.text = booking.description
                  }
                return cell
              }
            }
```

when running the app my console statements are as follows:

```
FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2023-02-08 11:19:01.213704+0100 SmartShovel2[68639:4216265] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800014] Cannot get flag for unregistered flag. SDK name, flag name: app_measurement, session_stitching_token_feature_enabled
2023-02-08 11:29:30.198469+0100 SmartShovel2[68639:4226571] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.devicecheck.error error 1.)'
In viewDidLoad
Reloading collection view data
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 0]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 6]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 1]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 7]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 2]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 3]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 4]
Configuring cell for indexPath [0, 5]
```

Why is it that loading the given view controller works but nothing is shown expect the collection view background?

All outlets appear to be connected, I have set custom classes and the reuse identifier.

I have tried re naming things and redoing all iboutlet connections, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Do you pass that if test `if let customerNameLabel = cell.customerNameLabel...`? Is your cell in a custom XIB or in the UICollectionView of your storyboard?

Comment: Hi, the cell is in the UIcollectionView in my storyboard.